# JavaScript: Get Element from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json

from a ASP.NET MVC Controller I receive a JSON object in the following form after doing a JQuery Request from the View:

```
[
  {
    "detectedLanguage": {
      "language": "de",
      "score": 1.0
    },
    "translations": [
      {
        "text": "This is a test.",
        "to": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

On the view side I like to parse for the "text" property to update a DIV content.

At the moment I am struggeling to get the element from the JSON object / array:

```
function doTranslation() {
    const textBody = document.getElementById("TextSource").value;

    var textData = { LanguageFrom: "", LanguageTo: "", TextSource: textBody, TextResult: "" };
    var requestData = JSON.stringify(textData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Translations/Translate",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: requestData,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = data[0].translations[0].text;
        },
        error: function () {
            document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = "Error";
        }
    });
}

$("#spinButton").on('click', doTranslation);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

This is the div I like to update in the same View with the JS code:

```
            <!-- Preview Tab-->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="preview">
                <div><a class="btn btn-success float-right" style="color:white;" id="spinButton"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i> &nbsp; Translate</a></div><br />
                <div id="PreviewText">Press the <strong>Translate</strong> Button to Translate your text Source...</div>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {    
    <script src="~/js/translate.js"></script>
```

And if I do something hard coded in the JavaScript code like

```
document.getElementById("PreviewText").innerHTML = "Hard coded text";
```

The text will be displayed.

Here is the debug output from Chrome:

[image]
And the error is that the div is not updated with the "text" content.

Console error is:

```
translate.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.success (translate.js:18)
    at fire (jquery.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3398)
    at done (jquery.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9548)
```

Where "data" shows the complete result when I hover over with the mouse. Hoverung over "translation" or "text" shows no content.

Maybe this clears it up a bit.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Obligatory mention that [There is no such thing as a JSON object/array](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: `data[0].translations[0].text` looks fine. What's happening instead? You didn't say what's happening instead of the expected result. Any errors, etc.

Comment: What exactly is happening when you run that code? Have you tried using `console.log` to see what `data` is?

Comment: You code looks correct. Some guesses about what may be going wrong: you might not have an element in the dom with an id of "PreviewText". You might not be getting back the JSON object you think you are. Who knows? Check the console.

Comment: @HereticMonkey hard to believe we've been complaining about that for almost a *decade*... without noticeable progress.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, it's likely a lost cause at this point, but I like that article :).

Comment: Now you've added the screenshot we can see that the JSON has been parsed in to a JS object. Try doing a `data = JSON.parse(data)` first ;)

Comment: @phuzi Thanks, that was the answer to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON hasn't been parsed and `data` is a string rather than a JS object.

Normally you should specify `dataType: "json"` in the AJAXparameters but that doesn't appear to be working (the server serializing the JSON first).

Check out what the server is actually returning or add `data = JSON.parse(data)` in your success function.